# Third call to api from angular to .net web api is slow in reaching the server

Tags: c#, angular, webapi

I am using these method for generating some pdf from the server first two calls are working fine but after the third call to same method it is taking time to reach server
Code for method in component is

```
        if (this.pdfSub != null) {
        this.pdfSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    
    this.pdfLoaded = false;

    debugger;
    
    this.pdfSub = this.fileService.getPDF(this.project).subscribe(response => {
        //this.project = this.storage.currentPorjectForGenerate;
        this.pdfSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        this.fileBlob = new Blob([response], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        this.isSaveShow = true;
        this.pdfLoaded = true;
        
      
    });
```

and code in the service is

```
    getPDF(model?: any, fileInfoId?: number): any {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    });
   

    return this.http1.post('/api/File/getPDF', model, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).
        pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
                return data;
            }), catchError(error => {
                return error;
            })
        )
     }
```

Comment: This is vague. “It is taking time to reach the server”, this doesn’t describe how long it does take in comparison to the first two requests. 

Also how are you measuring this? The response time or the time that is left the angular app or the time before the API received the request? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I attached the debugger just at the start of my web API method on first 2 request debugger hit right away but for third it took almost 7 secs